# How to explicitely close Spring context in a Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rmi

I have a Spring webapp running in Tomcat.

This app also needs to expose a service for remote access via RMI. I am using Spring's `RmiServiceExporter` to do this :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="${server.rmi.remoteServiceName}"/>
    <property name="service" ref="remoteFacade"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.ServiceInterface"/>
    <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="${server.rmi.registryPort}"/>
</bean>
```

It works well, but when I shutdown Tomcat, it hangs and I have to kill it and then manually kill the Java process it has created for the RMI registry. It seems to be because I should explicitely close (i.e. call the `close()` method) on the context that created the `RmiServiceExporter`, in this case my application context (not the web context). (source : https://issues.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5601)

How to achieve this (call the `close()` method on the context when the application is being stopped) in a webapp, where the context is created by a `ServletContextListener` (`org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`) ?

EDIT: My question was actually misleaded. The context is actually already being closed, and the RmiServiceExporter's destroy() method as well. The problem (tomcat unable to shutdown properly) seems to come from something else. May the users who spent time asnwering this question pardon my haste in posting it.

Comment: Could you please share what was causing the initial problem.(tomcat not shutting down properly) and it's solution. (Currently I am also facing a similar problem)

Comment: @Akash : Sorry that was a long time ago and I can't remember. Was not related to RMI though.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add destroy method to your bean definition:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="serviceName" value="${server.rmi.remoteServiceName}"/>
    <property name="service" ref="remoteFacade"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.ServiceInterface"/>
    <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="${server.rmi.registryPort}"/>
</bean>
```

2)if you have link to context instance add shutdown hook

```
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

Comment: RmiServiceExporter implements DisposableBean so IMHO it's not necessary to provide destroy method.

Comment: That's right. The exporter's destroy() method is being called already. See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your application context by using ContextLoaderListener as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create). It should close the context automatically for you.

Comment: I am already using org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener but it doesn't seem to be closing the context... Or maybe it does and the problem is somewhere else. I'll look into it.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? There are some try/catch in the destroy() method. Also you could using jVisualVM to profile it and find out why is not the VM shutdown.